# Retrieve data from new Firebase (Database)

Tags: xcode, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I can't retrieve data from new Firebase. After I touch to button (act()) nothing changes. I check all settings and read all documentations in Firebase web-site, but I can not understand why nothing is happening.

```
    import UIKit
import Firebase

var ref = FIRDatabaseReference.init()

class MainTovarViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
var items = [FIRDataSnapshot]()
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

}


@IBAction func act(sender: AnyObject) {
    ref.observeEventType(FIRDataEventType.Value) { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot!) in

        var newItems = [FIRDataSnapshot]()
        for item in snapshot.children {
            newItems.append(item as! FIRDataSnapshot)
        }

        self.items = newItems
        print("\(self.items)")
        self.collectionView!.reloadData()
    }
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    var result = 0
    if items.count != 0 {
        result = items.count
    }
    return result
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("MainTovarCollectionCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MainTovarCollectionCellCollectionViewCell
    cell.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "product_1"))
    cell.titletovar.text = items[indexPath.row].value!.objectForKey("TovarName") as! String

    return cell
}

}
```

And this:

```
2016-05-21 10:55:38.340 shoroo[95390:14237917] WARNING: Firebase 

Analytics App Delegate Proxy is disabled. To log deep link campaigns manually, call the methods in FIRAnalytics+AppDelegate.h.
2016-05-21 10:55:38.510 shoroo[95390:14237917] Configuring the default app.
2016-05-21 10:55:38.522 shoroo[95390:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> Firebase Analytics v.3200000 started
2016-05-21 10:55:38.523 shoroo[95390:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled
2016-05-21 10:55:38.529: <FIRInstanceID/WARNING> Failed to fetch APNS token Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=1001 "(null)"
2016-05-21 10:55:38.533: <FIRMessaging/INFO> FIRMessaging library version 1.1.0
2016-05-21 10:55:38.564 shoroo[95390:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> Firebase Analytics enabled
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3010 "REMOTE_NOTIFICATION_SIMULATOR_NOT_SUPPORTED_NSERROR_DESCRIPTION" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=REMOTE_NOTIFICATION_SIMULATOR_NOT_SUPPORTED_NSERROR_DESCRIPTION}
```

Comment: Did you include FIRApp.configure() in the application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method? Also, you should probably be using self.ref instead of just ref. Last thing is your pod file may not be configured correctly so the Analytics were not linked into your project. See [Updating Project](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-ios#update_your_cocoapods_dependencies_numbered)

Comment: Are you using any proxy ? See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37919569/firebase-not-working-with-https-proxy-in-android).

Answer (score 0):

Check your Database Authorization (rules). Try setting the rules to:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```